# QueryDsl: Updating table with two List parameters

Tags: java, collections, querydsl

I have a method to update all employees, which is called for every single employee at service layer.

```
public void updateEmployeeData(Long id, String account) {
        queryFactory.update(employee)
                .set(employee.employeeAccount, account)
                .where(employee.employeeId.eq(id))
                .execute();
    }
```

I have to optimize code and call it once with the Lists parameters.
For that reason I`ve turned id parameter into List.

```
public void updateEmployeeData(List<Long> ids, String account) {
        queryFactory.update(employee)
                .set(employee.employeeAccount, account)
                .where(employee.employeeId.in(ids))
                .execute();
    }
```

But how to iterate over each employees accounts? I cannot add IN clause to `set` part of query.

Is there any solution except enhanced For loop and iterating over every single employee?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL you would use a temporary table or a values clause, but unfortunately these are not available in JPQL. It is not possible to update multiple rows with distinct values in a JPA modification query. Consecutively, Querydsl does not support this as it is merely a query builder around JPQL.